# Export .wav from Audio Segment to AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, ibm-cloud, pydub

I'm using IBM's [Text-to-Speech API](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text?code=python) to run speaker detection. I used pydub to concatenate several .wav files into one, but I cannot pass an AudioSegment to IBM.

My questions are:

1. Can I export my file directly to an AWS S3 bucket, as I can later retrieve from there?
2. How else could I pass the AudioSegment? Can I encode it differently as a variable, so exporting it without saving it in memory, if that makes sense?

This is the formats IBM can read

- application/octet-stream
- audio/alaw (Required. Specify the sampling rate (rate) of the audio.)
- audio/basic (Required. Use only with narrowband models.)
- audio/flac
- audio/g729 (Use only with narrowband models.)
- audio/l16 (Required. Specify the sampling rate (rate) and optionally the number of channels (channels) and endianness (endianness) of the audio.)
- audio/mp3
- audio/mpeg
- audio/mulaw
- audio/ogg
- audio/ogg;codecs=opus
- audio/ogg;codecs=vorbis
- audio/wav
- audio/webm
- audio/webm;codecs=opus
- audio/webm;codecs=vorbis

I love pydub and it's been an amazing tool to work with so far. Thank you for making it!

Comment: The IBM API does not list a capability to store directly into Amazon S3, so your program would need to take the results from the IBM API and then store them in S3. This can either be done by creating a local file and then uploading the file to S3 or by keeping the data in a variable and passing it as the `Body` when creating a file in S3.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using python anyway, you could use [smart_open](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/smart_open) to treat a remote file in your object storage just like a locale one. This would allow you to stream the parts of the file to the os without having all of them in memory at once. Any format should be fine for the Objectstorage.